# .append in nested if does not add in order

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to find specific values, edit them and write them back to the list. If the values are not in the list, I append it as it is.

```
columns_list = ["Section", "String ENG", "AZ", "RU"]

loco_df = pd.read_csv("loco_auto_in.csv", usecols=columns_list)


main_file = open('bayg_t.txt','r')
eng_txt_list = []
az_txt_list = [] 

for line in main_file:
    eng_txt_list.append(line)

for i in loco_df["String ENG"]:
    for x in eng_txt_list:
        tr_strings = re.findall(r'msgid+."(.*?)"', x)
        if tr_strings:
            if i == tr_strings[0]: 
                e_x = x.replace(tr_strings[0], "00000000000xxxxx0000")
                az_txt_list.append(e_x)
            elif x not in az_txt_list: 
                az_txt_list.append(x)
                
        elif x not in az_txt_list: 
            az_txt_list.append(x)

            
print(az_txt_list)
```

The problem is: It always add the edit "00000000000xxxxx0000" to the end of the list however there are matches in the middle of the list. I have checked it but can't see the reason.

Thank you in advance.

Output:

```
['#: views/pages/announcements.php:59, templates/single/course/instructors.php:72\n', 'msgid "Courses"\n', 'msgstr ""\n', '\n', '#: templates/student-public-profile.php:121\n', 'msgid "Courses Completed"\n', '#: templates/student-public-profile.php:116\n', 'msgid "Courses Enrolled"\n', '#: classes/Options.php:272, classes/Tutor_Setup.php:412\n', 'msgid "Courses Per Page"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n']
```

Comment: Your strings are being added in the order in which `append` occurs. If you provide the txt and csv file, or at least enough for a reproducible example, then you can get better help.

Comment: I got the issue. The problem is I have two for loop which first time writing in a way I want then the only editable part is 00xx00 edit so it adds this part at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was nested for.

```
for i in loco_df["String ENG"]:
    string_list.append(i)
    
for x in eng_txt_list:
    tr_strings = re.findall(r'msgid+."(.*?)"', x)
    if tr_strings:
        if tr_strings[0] in string_list: 
            print("Matched!")
            e_x = x.replace(tr_strings[0], "00000000000xxxxx0000")
            az_txt_list.append(e_x)
        elif x not in az_txt_list: 
            az_txt_list.append(x)
                
    elif x not in az_txt_list: 
        az_txt_list.append(x)
print(az_txt_list)
```

Output:
`['#: templates/dashboard/assignments.php:34,\n', '#: templates/dashboard/purchase_history.php:21,\n', '#: templates/shortcode/tutor-instructor.php:27,\n', '#: views/pages/announcements.php:59, templates/single/course/instructors.php:72\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', 'msgstr ""\n', '\n', '#: templates/student-public-profile.php:121\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', '#: templates/student-public-profile.php:116\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', '#: classes/Options.php:272, classes/Tutor_Setup.php:412\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', '#: classes/Tutor_Setup.php:407\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', '#: classes/Utils.php:4770\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n', '#: templates/dashboard/settings/profile.php:50\n', 'msgid "00000000000xxxxx0000"\n']`